# VBA open powerpoint save with new name

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to simply open a powerpoint and then SaveAs with a new name.

I get "compile error: Method or data member not found"

```
Public Sub OpenPPTfinalOpp()
    Dim templatePath As String
    Set PPT = New PowerPoint.Application


    templatePath = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Automation").Range("D20")
    'templatePath = "C:\Users\[userName]\Desktop\test\Weekly Pack Update - Template.pptx"

    PPT.Visible = False
    Set PPT_pres = PPT.Presentations.Open(Filename:=templatePath)

    Set PPT_pres = PPT.Presentations.SaveAs(Filename:="C:\Users\[userName]\Desktop\test\Weekly Pack Update - Final.pptx")


End Sub
```

The code runs without the SaveAs line, ideally i could run this without opening the the powerpoint as this is just the first step before attaching it to an email.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by " ideally i could run this without opening the the powerpoint"? Are you looking for the problem with SaveAs or do you really want to ask a different question? If the SaveAs, why don't you have a PowerPoint tag in your question?

Comment: Your problem is that you're using `Set PPT_pres = PPT.Presentations.SaveAs` instead of `PPT_pres.SaveAs`. Copy/paste when you're tired has its pitfalls...

Comment: Yeah I think its time for a coffee break... Thank you Cindy

Comment: To do this without opening Powerpoint, for *any* filetype:  [`FileCopy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/language-reference-vba/articles/filecopy-statement)`ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Automation").Range("D20"), "C:\Users\[userName]\Desktop\test\Weekly Pack Update - Final.pptx"`

Comment: @Chronicidal - I'd write that up as an answer.  Or you could use the `CopyFile` from the `Scripting.FileSystemObject` which can be used to trap a "File already exists" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Upgraded from a Comment on the question:*
To do this without opening Powerpoint, for any filetype: [`FileCopy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/language-reference-vba/articles/filecopy-statement)`ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Automation").Range("D20"), "C:\Users\[userName]\Desktop\test\Weekly Pack Update - Final.pptx"`

To do this slightly more safely:

```
Public Function SafeCopy(Source As String, Destination As String) As Boolean
    SafeCopy = False
    'Source does not exist
    If Len(Dir(Source)) < 2 Then Exit Function
    'Clear destination file if it already exists
    If Len(Dir(Destination)) > 1 Then
        Kill Destination
        'Cannot clear destination
        If Len(Dir(Destination)) > 1 Then Exit Function
    End If
    'Do the actual copy
    FileCopy Source, Destination
    'Report on success/failure
    SaveCopy = (Len(Dir(Destination)) > 1)
End Function
```